External Monitor Shows Black Screen After Sleep on Ubuntu 24.04 (Intel UHD Graphics)
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a laptop with Intel UHD Graphics. I have two monitors connected:

Primary Monitor: External 4K display via DP-2.
Secondary Monitor: Built-in laptop display (eDP-1).

Problem:
After I lock my laptop and the screens turn off (e.g., after sleep or suspend), sometimes the external monitor won't wake up properly. When this happens, the external monitor shows a black screen, and the laptop monitor is treated as the primary display, even though the external monitor is still connected. The external monitor shows a low resolution (640x480) in xrandr but does not display anything. The only way to restore the external monitor is to power off the computer completely for a few minutes. A quick reboot does not resolve the issue.
System Info:

Ubuntu Version:
lsb_release -a  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS  
Release:        24.04  
Codename:       noble  


Kernel Version:
uname -r  
6.8.0-49-generic  


Graphics Card:
lspci | grep VGA  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)  



xrandr Output (Working):
xrandr --listmonitors
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767  
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 610mm x 350mm  
   2560x1440     59.91*+  
   1920x1440     59.90  
   1600x1200     59.87  
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.75  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.38  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   2048x1152     59.90  
   1920x1080     59.88  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+2560+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm  
   1920x1080     60.05*+  
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.96  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  

xrandr Output (Not Working):
xrandr --listmonitors
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767  
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm  
   1920x1080     60.05*+  
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      59.99  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.96  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
DP-2 connected 640x480+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm  
   640x480       59.38*+  
   320x240       59.52  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   640x350       59.77  

What I've Tried:

I've attempted various fixes posted online, including adjusting power settings and manually detecting the monitor with xrandr commands. However, none of these solutions have worked.
The only way to restore the external monitor to its correct resolution is to power off the laptop completely for a few minutes. A quick reboot does not solve the issue.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
